# Is it possible to Create a multi selection picklist / dropdown on imported Hosted XML process in azure DevOps services?

Tags: tfs-workitem, azure-devops-services

i cannot find any way o creating a Multi Selection picklist or any other field with that functionality.

**i am using an imported process **

[image]

I cannot add extension similar to other process

[image]

Is it possible to create such a field using xml edit only?

I have searched and looked  in the following https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-multivalue-control but i cannot add extension  due my process limitations